# When is dowry (Haq-Meh'r) farz?

Tags: nikah, talaq, mehr

Assalam-0-Alaikum,

I want to know **(with references to authentic sources)** that is the dowry amount (Haq-Meh'r) still payable to bride if the couple only did the Nikkah (then the bride went to another country) and they didn't live together for even one night and didn't even consummated the marriage and then they got divorced?

I have heard that dowry is not applicable until the bride spends the night with the groom. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Surah al-Baqarah, 236-237 :

Translation :

> *"There is no sin on you if you divorce women when you have not yet touched them nor fixed for them an amount. So, give them benefit, a
>   rich man according to his means and a poor one according to his means
>   — a benefit in the recognized manner, an obligation on the virtuous.
>   And if you divorce them before you have touched them, while you have
>   already fixed for them an amount, then there is one half of what you
>   have fixed, unless they (the women) forgive, or forgives the one in
>   whose hand lies the marriage tie. And it is closer to Taqwa* that you
>   forgive. And do not forget being graceful to one another. Surely,
>   Allah is watchful of what you do."*

As per this ayah, if your marriage has not been consummated, then you will have to pay 50% of the dower amount that was fixed at the time of nikkah. If your wife doesn't want the dower amount then she can forgive it and you are not liable for it anymore.

And Allah SBT knows best.

Answer (score 1):

No that's wrong information to you. mahr is farz on husband to pay it to his wife, if they consummate. On the first night, second or third whensoever. But it only gets farz when they consummate. Otherwise, mahr is not farz.

Secondly, just for clarification, that is not called Dowry, dowry is the stuff that family of the bride sends alongwith their daughter to the house of husband. The price that husband pays is known as Haq-Meh'r.

Comment: Oh I see. 
I was indeed talking about Haq-Meh'r. Could you provide me a link to source (hadith maybe) so I can confirm that _Haq-Meh'r is only farz after consummation of marriage_

Comment: I don't remember that reference right now, but just a week or 2 weeks ago I heard this in a Khutba after prayer :) That's why I shared it here with you :)